# What does operand like 32i64 mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 32bit-64bit

Please help me understand this expression:

```
(dwStreamSizeMax >> 32i64)
```

I've never seen operands like 32i64 before. Thank you.

Comment: Neither has google. Perhaps it is a simple `#define` ?

Comment: Preprocessor tokens can't start with digits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From MSDN [C++ Integer Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx):

> 64-bit integer-suffix: i64 LL ll

That is, `32i64` would be 64-bit sized constant of integer type, of value of `32`. That is, it is `(__int64) 32`, or `(int64_t) 32`.

> `dwStreamSizeMax >> 32i64`

Note that in the quoted expression even for 64-bit `dwStreamSizeMax` maximal shift bit count which makes sense is 63, which fits into 8-bit value (`BYTE`), hence 64-bit size specifier there is redundant.

Comment: The specifier is actually completely redundant; the type of the right-hand operand does not have any effect on the left-hand one, for the shift operators. (Unlike for the arithmetic operators).  Maybe it is a bug and the code was meant to be `((uint64_t)dwStreamSizeMax) >> 32`.

Comment: Also, if the `dw` prefix on `dwStreamSizeMax` is a correct indication that it's a `DWORD`, then shifting it right by 32 is undefined behavior since `DWORD`'s are 32-bit types on Windows (even Win64).

Comment: And if @MattMcNabb's guess is correct that the intent was to promote `dwStreamSizeMax` to a 64-bit int type, then the expression might as well have been replaced with `0`.

Comment: Thank you! I found this expression in Jeffrey Richter's book. Here is a full version of it: `::CreateFileMapping(hstream, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, (DWORD) (dwStreamSizeMax >> 32i64), (DWORD) dwStreamSizeMax, NULL);`. I also agree that 32i64 operand might be easily replaced with simple 32.

Comment: Someone tell Mr. Richter that his code has undefined behaviour

Comment: Which book and where? A search of "Windows via C/C++, Fifth Edition" pdf for "dwStreamSizeMax" didn't find this snippet for me.

Comment: [Here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads155/sourcecode/windows/system/688754/windows%E6%A0%B8%E5%BF%83%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E6%BA%90%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81/reply_1_390833/17-MMFSparse/MMFSparse.cpp__.htm) it says "Jeffrey Richter 2000". No idea if this is from real book and not yet in errata.

Comment: Looks like it's an older version of the code that's fixed in the 5th Edition. In the older code, `dwStreamSizeMax` is a `SIZE_T` (so it would be a 64-bit type on Win64 systems) and the expression is attempting to get the high 32-bits. That'll work for 64-bit systems, but is still undefined behavior on 32-bit systems. In the 5th edition, the size information is passed as two separate high/low DWORDs.

Answer (score 1):

It's the suffix for a 64-bit integer literal, not unlike `L` for a `long` or `ULL` for an `unsigned long long`. However, I believe it's a Microsoft-ism and not portable C++.

C++11 only provides suffixes for `long` and `long long` types (and their `unsigned` counterparts), the latter which is guaranteed to be 64 bits *or more.*